# Converting a native browser event object to a jQuery event object

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am assigning an event handler function to an element through the native browser onclick property:

```
document.getElementById('elmtid').onclick = function(event) { anotherFunction(event) };
```

When I'm in `anotherFunction(event)`, I want to be able to use the event object like I would with the event object you get in jQuery through the `.on()` method. I want to do this because the jQuery event object has properties and methods such as `.pageX`, `.pageY` and `.stopPropagation()` that work across all browsers.

So my question is, after I've passed in the native browser event object into `anotherFunction()`, how can I turn it into a jQuery event? I tried `$(event)`, but it didn't work.

The obvious question here is: why don't you just use jQuery `.on`, `.bind`, `.click` etc to assign your event handling functions? The answer: I'm building a page that has a huge table with lots of clickable things on it. Unfortunately this project requires that the page MUST render quickly in IE6 and IE7. Using `.on` et al in IE6 and IE7 creates DOM leaks and eats up memory very quickly (test for yourself with Drip: http://outofhanwell.com/ieleak/index.php?title=Main_Page). Setting onclick behavior via `.onclick` is the only option I have to render quickly in IE6 and IE7.

Comment: Not putting this as an answer, because it's just an idea - not an idea I *like*. You could do `$.event.fix(event)` - which is what jQuery does internally. The keyword being "internally", meaning you shouldn't assume it will still work the same way in the next version of jQuery.

Comment: Try `new jQuery.Event(nativeEvent)`.  I don't know if it will work.  requires 1.6 or later.

Comment: Thanks TheKaneda + DwB -- I'll give those a try and see how it works. Feel free to add as an answer.

Comment: If `event.pageX` doesn't work, then maybe try `event.originalEvent.pageX`. I haven't tried this myself so I am not 100% sure of it.

Comment: Yeah, actually, `jQuery.Event()` doesn't normalize anything at all, contrary to what the docs imply (but don't actually state).

Comment: This is strange, using @DwB approach, the event was partially turned into a jQuery event, .stopPropagation() is on the event object, but not .pageX, see screenshot: http://postimage.org/image/3vdq6w73p/  jQuery must be doing something else to add the .pageX .pageY properties.

Comment: AFAIK, `jQuery.Event()` is for creating synthetic events (typically prior to `.trigger()`), not for native event normalization.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Too long for a comment... Because the documentation is a bit vague on this... (I'm looking at 1.7.1 in the following)

`jQuery.Event(event, props)`:

- creates a new object
- sets its `type` property to the event's `type` property.
- sets `isDefaultPrevented` by normalized calls to all the ways to check if default is prevented.
- sets `originalEvent` to reference the event you passed in.
- adds an arbitrary set of properties provided by the `props` object argument.
- sets a timestamp.
- marks object "fixed".

What you get is basically a new object with a few additional properties and a reference to the original event - no normalization other than `isDefaultPrevented`.

`jQuery.event.fix(event)`:

- ignores objects that have already been marked "fixed".
- makes a writable copy (by way of `jQuery.Event()`) and normalizes the properties mentioned [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

**ETA:**

Actually, looking closer at the code, `jQuery.event.fix()` should work - in the way described by @Beetroot-Beetroot. It's all that jQuery does to create the jQuery event object in an event dispatch.

Comment: @Elliot.Bradshaw - http://jsfiddle.net/Rpgrf/ - but it's pretty much what Beetrot-Beetrot said.

Comment: Answer accepted. First to post on $.event.fix(event) and first to post full working example, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You want [`jQuery.event.fix`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L524).

#### `new jQuery.Event(nativeEvent)`

- [Stores `nativeEvent` as the `originalEvent` property.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L641)
- [Handles some bubbling logic.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L644-647)
- [Timestamps the event](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L660)
- [Marks the event as "jQuery's got this"](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L663)
- [Gives it all the bubbling/default-preventing functions](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L675-714).

Note at this point the event doesn't have any "eventy" properties, just `originalEvent`, `timeStamp`, and the bubbling/default-preventing functions.

#### `jQuery.event.fix(nativeEvent)`

- [Does all the above](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L535)
- [Figures out specific fixes ("fix hook") it will need to apply depending on the event type](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L532)
- [Copies over a default set of properties from `nativeEvent`, plus specific ones from the fix hook](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L537-540)
- [Fixes cross-browser issues with the `target` and `metaKey` properties](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L542-555)
- [Applies specific cross-browser fixes and normalizations for the fix hook](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L557).

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('elmtid').onclick = anotherFunction;
```

with:

```
function anotherFunction(evt){
    evt = $.event.fix(evt || window.event);//Note need for cross-browser reference to the native event
    ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wrzpb/

Comment: That's cool @Elliot.Bradshaw. The most important thing is you've got an answer.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! `evt = $.event.fix(evt || window.event);` I don't know why that little snippet is so hard to find. Seems like something that should be in jQuery's docs. Thank you!!!

Comment: @todd, it should be noted that this is a pretty weird thing to do. It uses a feature of jQuery to fix non-jQuery javascript - ie. a hybrid approach. With jQuery installed on the page, it's typically better to opt for a 100% jQuery solution, though I understand that may mean translating and re-qualifying old code.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot OK, thank you. Maybe there's some other issue with my code then. I was having problems with the jQuery event object in Firefox and this seemed to have fixed it, but I will go back and take a closer look.

Comment: @todd, if necessary, raise a new question then post a link here so I'm alerted to it.